# Not able to position popover without the arrow

Tags: ios, swift

I am displaying a popover (Present as Popover) as a dropdown when the user clicks on nav bar title (which is a label + an image). I was not able to set the nav bar title as popover's anchor view. So for anchor view, I added a clear 1x1 button that sits right below the nav bar (button.top = safe area.top)

I am able to position the popover along the y-axis by changing the y value in sourceRect.

```
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 1, height: 1)
```

[image]

It looks good, except I don't want the arrow in the popover. So I added this line of code.

```
    popover?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
```

Now, I am not able to position the popover correctly. It doesn't matter what y value I specify in sourceRect, the popover stays at the same place.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are not accounting for the navigation bar. I don't see your sourceView value, but I would assume it is the view controller's view, which would explain the difference. You could subtract the height of your nav bar as well, which should get what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that that is not how to suppress the arrow. The right way is to provide a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView that doesn’t draw the arrow.

However it would be better not to do this at all. Popovers have arrows. If you don’t want the arrow, don’t use a popover. Write a custom presented view controller instead.